What's the price of banana?
An Iranian merchant has immigrated to the USA and opens his fruit store there.
He labels his fruits in both Persian and English with the costs in dollars:
سیب (Apple): 33$ per kilo
پرتقال (Orange): 67$ per kilo
کیوی (Kiwifruit): 42$ per kilo

What's the price of موز (Banana) per kilo?
This is an original puzzle

it's one banana. how much could it cost?

He has a lot of fruits. He has, say, 100 kilograms of apples, 200 kg of oranges, and 50 kg of bananas. If I say it in singular it doesn't necessarily mean he has only one of each!

@EtackSxchange juicifer is referring to a popular scene from Arrested Development.

@juicifer I'm sorry for my wrong interpretation

And the price for bananas is ...

 $31 per kilo

... because ...

 Without knowing anything about Persian, I still can move the cursor over these words and discover how they split into characters.



 From there the formula becomes pretty obvious:
 price = (number of letters) x 10 + (number of dots).

 So the word for banana having 3 letters and 1 dot, the price is $31.


This is one of those cases where it might even be easier to see the answer if you don't speak the language! Btw I don't think the dots are diacritical marks here, if I understand correctly they're part of the letter just like the dot above the English j. (Never learned Persian but that's my understanding.)

I checked and yes, you are probably right about the dots.  I removed the remark.

@FlorianF Excellent!
